Scrapy: Preventing Data Persistence and Cross-Request Contamination
Intro
I've edited the post to simplify and clarify the content and included the proposed solutions.
All issues were resolved using download delays and dupefilter (as suggested by @wRAR).
However, with the download delay enabled, the process now takes 20 minutes instead of 1 minute.
Is there an alternative way to ensure consistent data without significantly increasing runtime?
I'm using Scrapy to crawl pages and extract data into a JSON file, but I'm encountering data consistency issues. Specifically, some fields retain or duplicate data from previous responses, resulting in incorrect field values in the output.
Code

I have all the URLs saved in a .txt file, with each URL on a separate line.
The code defines the "items" to be extracted.
A class is defined using CrawlSpider.
The URLs from the .txt file are loaded into the start_urls list.
Each URL is parsed.

from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


class Claselicitacion(Item):
    objeto_contrato = Field()
    presupuesto_base = Field()
    url = Field()

class LicitacionCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'licitacion_crawl'
    ua = UserAgent()
    custom_settings = {
        "REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION": "2.7",
        'USER_AGENT': ua.random,
        #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
        'FEEDS': {
            '2_ProjectFinder.json': {
                'format': 'json',
                'encoding': 'utf-8',
            },
        },
    'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': False,  # Disable caching
    'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
        #INCONSISTENCY IN NUMBER OF ITEMS SOLVED BY ADDING DUPEFILTER AS SUGGESTED BY @wRAR
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,  # Set a delay of 2 seconds between requests
    'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': True,  # Randomize the delay to make requests less predictable
    #'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,  # Make one request at a time
    }

    with open('1_DeepLinks.txt', 'r') as file:
        start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file if line.strip()]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=r'deeplink%3Adetalle_licitacion'),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=False,
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = ItemLoader(item=Claselicitacion(), response=response)

        if response.xpath('//li[@id="fila4_columna2"]'):
            item.add_xpath('objeto_contrato', '//li[@id="fila4_columna2"]//span[@class="outputText"]/text()')
        else:
            item.add_value('objeto_contrato', 'NO DATA FOUND')

        if response.xpath('//li[@id="fila5_columna2"]'):
            item.add_xpath('presupuesto_base', '//li[@id="fila5_columna2"]//span[@class="outputText"]/text()')
        else:
            item.add_value('presupuesto_base', 'NO DATA FOUND')

        item.add_value('url', response.url)

        yield item.load_item()

.txt file
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=cApMdjrnFxvkY6rls5tG9A%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=bPC0z57zEdT%2B3JAijKO%2Bkg%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=p01IZQBxnA0wYTJJ03sHog%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=ywAdehRW01iKeVWTb9Scog%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=%2BLSRO96X%2BwA%2Bk2oCbDosIw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=Dei084jNCcP9pbnDwlaUlg%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=k6KakN%2BZYBMeIBJRHQiPkQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=HK%2FlAibJXBwaF6cS8TCh%2FA%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=RdyFawO%2B9o1xseVhcqrkhw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=vs5sDIcT4IJ%2FP7lJ7Fu0SA%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=eCX0B1KHHnmKeVWTb9Scog%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=d2IhCu3FgMoaF6cS8TCh%2FA%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=kDeiqJlZZ4l9PLkba5eRog%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=Kv59E6Ou73GkU02jNGj1Fw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=Klk6HCTpUR%2BP66GS%2BONYvQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=voH3FLNnAVWdkQsA7ROvsg%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=bYA8A476k368ebB%2FXTwy0A%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=l1WennZeqsx9PLkba5eRog%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=bR4siR3c8jc2wEhQbcAqug%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=UT49w505%2BJ0IYE3ZiZ%2BxmQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=5xBvPaU72OJPpzdqOdhuWg%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=DBYw2PHvQ1836J9Lctlsuw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=p9H459uP%2FRwZDGvgaZEVxQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=ac6Sy2Nw5ZvECtSnloz%2BZQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=CHIb93%2FPxJIeIBJRHQiPkQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=1253hczyXjSopEMYCmrbmw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=JGV3KkFBdVDE6P%2FuLemXRw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=Ybczh91UUkm7JOCXkOhcDg%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=kWrVjQJjT3N70UvEyYJSGw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=eBIlJKy0naW2gkLQ8TeYKA%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=s4x6ayYZ0p2S81gZFETWmA%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=vyFADvkBaL8%2B1TMyIiZmzw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=VNFIQXgMOP8eIBJRHQiPkQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=NeJBEfrP%2FzNVkTabT%2FRM8A%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=lIAcO4TA4DdJ8Trn0ZPzLw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=iUieCIzaBtl9Zh%2FyRJgM8w%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=r%2FoUMWAqF%2FIadbH3CysQuQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=5crGaOEWZb5t5r0ngvMetA%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=eajD4ChSFXxxseVhcqrkhw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=lGyZLzj63IecTfjQf3USOg%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=QNSyrOmi0L0SugstABGr5A%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=8Ms%2FdQrWAjwBPRBxZ4nJ%2Fg%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=EzeNQiVn6SaXQV0WE7lYPw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=S2hoL5aAU8QSugstABGr5A%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=q65WCykX4LSrz3GQd5r6SQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=2AvvWflgGJyXQV0WE7lYPw%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=twp99qzEoH4uf4aBO%2BvQlQ%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=0UasHuzxmW2iEJrVRqloyA%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=aueRKZ771qTnSoTX3z%2F7wA%3D%3D
https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/poc?uri=deeplink:detalle_licitacion&idEvl=3k4%2FDZXRaiV7h85%2Fpmmsfw%3D%3D

Results (.json file)
1. I'm getting 44 fields (the .txt file has 50 URLs). #SOLVED ADDING DUPEFILTER AS SUGGEST BY @wRAR
2. The first three items have the same name and budget but different URLs.#SOLVED WITH DOWNLOAD DELAYS
3. After manual verification, each of these three URLs actually has a different budget and name.#SOLVED WITH DOWNLOAD DELAYS
[
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de redes de agua potable de fibrocemento en las calles travesía conca de la safor, ademas e la renovación de redes de aguas pluviales en la calle paseo alcalde miguel faus y carrer ronda, así como la instalación de analizador de turbidez e implantación de fuentes publicas de agua potable filtrada por sistema de ósmosis en diferentes emplazamientos"], "presupuesto_base": ["76,774.94"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcqxCoAgEADQT7qpoMDBoZqaS5c4PInL06RE-vwcHzywsINNWPnEwndCaTbkfRZOYSRfUMQfwo4LuhZgAwuWaaoCxum80vWk-avB9I-8XVkGrRTkGPUPeMSn2Q!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de redes de agua potable de fibrocemento en las calles travesía conca de la safor, ademas e la renovación de redes de aguas pluviales en la calle paseo alcalde miguel faus y carrer ronda, así como la instalación de analizador de turbidez e implantación de fuentes publicas de agua potable filtrada por sistema de ósmosis en diferentes emplazamientos"], "presupuesto_base": ["76,774.94"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjs828E7P9tKMinXxTPZ28gjwCMwOyA21t9Qtycx0Bf-5y3w!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de redes de agua potable de fibrocemento en las calles travesía conca de la safor, ademas e la renovación de redes de aguas pluviales en la calle paseo alcalde miguel faus y carrer ronda, así como la instalación de analizador de turbidez e implantación de fuentes publicas de agua potable filtrada por sistema de ósmosis en diferentes emplazamientos"], "presupuesto_base": ["76,774.94"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcqxCoAgEADQr3G-poigwaKIGgsyl7hU6uiyBrHfz_HBAw0KtMdIBwZ6PHLyap17mfxVWheQ2W1MhgKaFGABDZpsGxnWfhQZS9oHVX_Y5WYq5uYUmawqeO9b_pxbrGA!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de la red de abastecimiento de agua potable en calles Jose María de la Fuente y San Isidoro de Ciudad Real."], "presupuesto_base": ["73,691.96"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcqxDkAwEADQTzqDAUkHwSoWoV3ktBc5rqdDw-8zvuSBgxWc4sMHZr4V5bcNRElYryZQRhHahD1n9H-ABRw4DsMjYHvioirPsfNTnXbtX8FZDmMgxdh-dRs-gw!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de la red de abastecimiento de agua potable en calles Jose María de la Fuente y San Isidoro de Ciudad Real."], "presupuesto_base": ["73,691.96"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjkwKcDapMzatcU0K0jb0cM7O8_bWz021t9Qtycx0BDiAL2w!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["renovacion de redes de agua potable de fibrocemento en calle crist rey, instalacion de analizador de turbidez e implantacion de fuentes publicas de agua potable filtrada por sistema de osmosis en diferentes emplazamientos del municipio de Daimus"], "presupuesto_base": ["77,229.29"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjvXOyzTycQwpCg7QDzMzcg7X9_SLLAm1t9Qtycx0BR9InjQ!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Contracte d'obres per la renovació de la xarxa d'aigua al carrer Empordà al nucli de Pinedes de l'Armengol. Substitució de canonada d'aigua potable en baixa en sòl urbà."], "presupuesto_base": ["148,284.23"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjtX2Cg_wtzSK0yx21s43ynZNc8os9y21t9Qtycx0B3OltPA!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Obres  d'actuacions diverses al Dipòsit de Farners."], "presupuesto_base": ["53,110.16"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcqxDkAwEADQTzpGkg4dTDZEtYuc9sLFtTU0xN8zvuSBgwVcwpt3LJwTym8biC7hdLaBCorQKuy5oP8DGHDgOHS3gH0fHegYTFVzT7OZtmb0eVcKrhj1B4i-1Ew!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de redes de agua potable de fibrocemento en las calles Travesía Conca de la Safor, además de la renovación de redes de aguas pluviales en la calle Paseo Alcalde Miguel Faus y carrer Ronda, así como la instalación de analizador de turbidez e implantación de fuentes públicas de agua potable filtrada por sistema de osmosis en diferentes emplazamientos en Beniflà."], "presupuesto_base": ["76,774.94"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcqxDkAwEADQT7oEg0gMHfoBLOgi12tTxymi-H0dX_LAwAgm4ssBEx8RJXty3p_CcWucTyjiZ2HihJQDDGDAsNOvwGT76ua-pHql4tNLZ0ldT2hbOPdd_Tj6ctU!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Substitució comptadors d'aigua analògics a digitals"], "presupuesto_base": ["78,172.29"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjg1Iq3RLL_bUt8w0rilPDMpILi7Izym1t9Qtycx0B-Ejvjg!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Obras de renovación de redes hidraulicas y mejora de impulsión de red de agua potable en Calle San Benito de Fuencaliente"], "presupuesto_base": ["51,610.82"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcrBCoAgDADQT5rRLehgEJS3ICh3iZEio6VCUn1-HR88QFgBI90cqHCKJL-t8z4Lx6NxvpCI34R3LrT_ARZAQHb9LWCzqkacujdq9djZGFVfQwptC_k89Qf2n2Dy/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de la tubería de traída de la Fuente Grande hasta el edificio del motor y optimización de equipo de bombeo”. \r\nPlan Inversiones 22-23/701"], "presupuesto_base": ["93,431.81"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjy4pNi108k0NMPL1UDQLMc7zM3UoNgh1tbfULcnMdAffvgaQ!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejora de la red de abastecimiento del municipio de Alcolea de Calatrava (Ciudad Real)"], "presupuesto_base": ["64,310.51"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/Dco7CoAwDADQI0VHBQcVodBRsbWLxDZIMP0MxfPr-OCBAwsu4cs3Vs4J5fcRiIpwevpAFUXoFPZc0f8BDDhwHJZX4KDZNlOrlUpR0262q1t9vocBSozjB3jIPXg!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Obras para rehabilitación del pavimento interior de la Plaza San Fernando, rehabilitación de la jardinería y mejoras en la accesibilidad e infraestructuras urbanas."], "presupuesto_base": ["300,459.50"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcoDqjDwznEuN3dJ98xPdzJKDLUKcM1QNHG1t9Qtycx0B_de8JA!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Obras de instalaciones de recogida y depuración de las aguas residuales en el casco urbano de Errezil (1.fase)"], "presupuesto_base": ["188,238.98"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjkyIdLRxNzM2yjc0sUpOcVA0iQsorDRxtbfULcnMdAYp0tHw!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de la Red de Abastecimiento en Avda. del Torreón y Paseo Pablo Picasso de Ciudad Real"], "presupuesto_base": ["158,995.90"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcoxCoAwDADAJ2XRQaGDoIs4iIs2i8Q2lNDYKhTfb8eDA4QDMNEngYrkRFptPfOjkmLvuZAqnypOCrkaYAcEFD99CjaOLO-siI126xIvannLwRh47nv4AfSuT38!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de la Red de Abastecimiento en Avda. del Torreón y Paseo Pablo Picasso de Ciudad Real"], "presupuesto_base": ["158,995.90"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjy_I9jN18_PIcw8JTsgOLHc2D_MuK021t9Qtycx0Bs6cGzQ!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["construcción nueva captación en elcoaz para abastecimiento de agua"], "presupuesto_base": ["50,618.92"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcoxCoAwDADAJwUHBwUHBzcHcalmkdiGEhqjYik-X8eDA4QF0KhIpCynkf5eA_OlYqkNnEmVNxUvmfwfwAECShiKwqqVYzPk-3mbaUw71TyfsevgOo7-AxdlbVM!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejora en el abastecimiento en alta de Burguete conducción desde el manantial al deposito regulador con  PEAD-110mm"], "presupuesto_base": ["66,597.66"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjvctMLV3N_EvNjd2zQw2Msvzcswzdym1t9Qtycx0BQwdD7Q!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Obras correspondientes al Proyecto Plan de Obras 2023 Renovación de Redes de Abastecimiento de Agua Potable en Puebla de Don Rodrigo"], "presupuesto_base": ["63,127.10"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjnT08kyyNVQ0CKrw8Uz2dvII8AjMDsgNtbfULcnMdAS3u5Sw!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["La millora de l’eficiència hídrica de la xarxa d’abastament d’aigua potable dels carrers del Pla de Manlleu, per millorar la qualitat de vida i serveis proporcionats per l’Ajuntament. Les obres consitiran en:\n⎯ Substitució d’uns 100m de la canonada de fibrociment de 50 mm de diàmetre en el tram entre el dipòsit de distribució i el nucli urbà del Pla de Manlleu. \n⎯ Substitució de 40 escomeses de plom per equivalents estàndards."], "presupuesto_base": ["51,509.87"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjTSucygISQ82N_L0CCqpSCv1TMkrD021t9Qtycx0B0yOBVg!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Ejecución proyecto \"Abastecimiento caserios Atxurtza. Fase 1 impulsión depósito Ezkio a nuevo depósito Atxurtza\""], "presupuesto_base": ["247,576.09"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjE5PNgiuN_MpNo8pcnUuC83Lyq7SjAm1t9Qtycx0BuYfnDw!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de la red de Abastecimiento en calle Madrilas "], "presupuesto_base": ["122,111.84"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjQ0NMLMtNDUy1vQw8I12NozKjtCtyA21t9Qtycx0BvqWrgA!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejora, modernización y dotación en las infraestructuras y servicios en el polígono industrial “CASCO URBANO/SECTOR S5” de Museros, incluido en el programa de Parques Empresariales del IVACE para el ejercicio 2023."], "presupuesto_base": ["122,361.12"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjCyw9TEwtSwNUDYLKo1zcy9ITo1zDKgJtbfULcnMdAflDcdc!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de la red de abastecimiento en las calles Grecia, Noruega y Portugal de Ciudad Real."], "presupuesto_base": ["191,559.99"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjXZwiy40CPMoCDS2MzbwsfZJLcopLy21t9Qtycx0B4ud3xg!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejora en el abastecimiento en alta de Burguete conducción desde el manantial al deposito regulador con  PEAD-110mm"], "presupuesto_base": ["66,597.66"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjvdzDjL2z3ZxSwlxczQJUDUp9UnMjgsptbfULcnMdAd2X86g!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejora del abastecimiento en el diseminado de Rodacanters en Millena\r\n"], "presupuesto_base": ["63,218.56"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjyyrdHF3Ksp0SfSy0DUN8Kz0zo3Krym1t9Qtycx0BU5_uvQ!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de redes de agua potable de fibrocemento"], "presupuesto_base": ["84,072.74"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQj_VK9nFzTigJUDar8wrJDEpNCVA2CfC0cbW31C3JzHQFWfu8j/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Obras de mejora del deposito de Anotzibar"], "presupuesto_base": ["31,772.94"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjs8OLwrICvbJCjP3MDULLXCsjvYLdy21t9Qtycx0BGaNOZQ!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["obras correspondientes al proyecto renovación de redes de agua potable de fibrocemento en av. Jaime i, agüera pluviales borro, cambio de analizador de cloro e implantacion de fuentes publicas de agua potable filtrada por sistema de osmosis en el municipio de Ròtova"], "presupuesto_base": ["77,265.49"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/Dco7CoAwDADQI2UVwUFBUUFtHfxkkWCDBNPqUDy_HR88QNgAA31yUZQnkCbvjvlVCXfuOJIqHyqnRDpTgBUQUFz9KezL2HR2u4bJZNxV_dxaMbctCni9L3-Df_rM/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Reacciona 2022 la Font d'en Carròs. Renovación de tubería en la urbanización del Tossal. Instalación de válvula reguladora de presión  en el casco urbano. Instalación de fuente de ósmosis. Instalación de equipos de telelectura de contadores de agua potable."], "presupuesto_base": ["82,367.89"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcqxCoAgEADQT7poiqChoKFsCQLTJQ495PAyBxH6-xofPLBwgk1YOWDhJ6H8Np4oC6fYeyooQpew44LuD6DBgmU_VwFD0yKrepuEug1x27uDjBqHAfJ9jx_0w9bo/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["El objeto del contrato es la ” Obra de refuerzo del abastecimiento de agua a Tárano y su zona de influencia, en el término municipal de Cangas de Onís”."], "presupuesto_base": ["94,912.32"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcpBCoAgEADAJ21FRAQeOtQHCsy9xKISS6sJSdTv8zgwgLABRnr4oMxXJCk2zvskHM_B-Uwifhe2nMmWABoQkN30CJi7fTv6DFapWfr6wHladRiVghTC-APNVyTy/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Contracte d'obres per la nova captació d’aigua al riu Escrita d'Espot"], "presupuesto_base": ["41,822.55"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/DcqxCoAgEADQTzqaosAhqqXFSUqXuFT08LQGaejrc3zwwMABpuBLASvdBblZO-8fppJG5ysy-5PJUkXbAuxgwJBbXwatL_vFoVMq5X6T85FktEsQAp6cpx_K_Svy/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejoras en la red de abastecimiento del Ayuntamiento de Riotorto"], "presupuesto_base": ["49,975.01"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQji1QN8kN9wx0L3VQNPBNTkjyMnSuLA0sDbW31C3JzHQGSEVZM/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejora, modernización y dotación en las infraestructuras y servicios en el polígono industrial “CASCO URBANO/SECTOR S5” de Museros, incluido en el programa de Parques Empresariales del IVACE para el ejercicio 2023."], "presupuesto_base": ["122,361.12"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjczwdk_1NQhxNXFK8LEKK8gyiAqp8ym1t9Qtycx0BQGuQWw!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Contracte d'obres per la nova captació d’aigua al riu Escrita d'Espot"], "presupuesto_base": ["41,822.55"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjc9wro3yqssyMPVOTQ9KyAtOMQ4P9021t9Qtycx0BUvF1JQ!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Proyecto de mejora del abastecimiento municipal de agua potable del municipio de Villaverde de Rioja (La Rioja)"], "presupuesto_base": ["55,725.67"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjg40y8n1MEx1DLQKDS9OLSxyd3ItMHW1t9Qtycx0BHF21Gg!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Fase II Reurbanización de la calle Mayor entre la Plaza Santa Ana y Avenida Aragón en Belver de Cinca"], "presupuesto_base": ["122,857.09"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/Dco7CoAwDADQI8VJQXBw6CqK0E8WCTZIMNYOpYKn1_HBAwQPmKjKQUXuRPo7ROasks4-ciFV3lR2KbT_ARwgoERTFYJ5eVrEpnYlv9jGmU7D_AwD5OsaP3QO-L8!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Nuevo abastecimiento caserios Zuzuarregi -zuzuarregi txiki, Anduti, Lizarribar  del barrio  Egileor"], "presupuesto_base": ["64,790.44"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjA_2CK4v8czMNfAyCS9OLSxyd3ItMHW1t9Qtycx0BGEiWcA!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación de redes de aguas pluviales del municipio de Beniflà así como la instalación de analizador de cloro e implantación de fuentes publicas de agua potable filtrada por sistema de osmosis."], "presupuesto_base": ["79,695.29"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjC81Mw50rsyNMfIKLqozdA1NMi8yCA21t9Qtycx0BDucj1Q!!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["ejecución de la obra renovación de redes de agua potable de fibrocemento en calle crist rey, cambio de analizador de cloro e implantacion de fuentes publicas de agua potable filtrada por sistema de osmosis en el municipio de daimús."], "presupuesto_base": ["89,103.18"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjE0tTg7yjzM0NC0PygvNDIoyrVA3Myx1tbfULcnMdAfrRc4Y!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejora del abastecimiento del núcleo de\r\nBárcabo"], "presupuesto_base": ["139,082.35"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjjbNNVA1coiKCEjPDzDMsTFUNCnJzi9PKbW31gQxHAInuUEg!/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Renovación Redes de Suministro Plaza de la Iglesia y parte de Calle Vallat"], "presupuesto_base": ["138,420.17"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/Dcq9CoAgEADgR7poCQKHBgmaasmfJQ41OTqtQYzePscPPrCgwWasFLHQnZGbjQ_hYcrX6ENB5nAwOSroWgAFFix5WRlMP9WqTo7z8ult75Qc2KyvEPCkNP2900up/"]},
{"objeto_contrato": ["Mejora del abastecimiento del núcleo de\r\nBárcabo"], "presupuesto_base": ["139,082.35"], "url": ["https://contrataciondelestado.es/wps/portal/!ut/p/b0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjU1JTC3Iy87KtUlJLEnNyUuNzMpMzSxKTgQr0w_Wj9KMyU1zLcvQjLXyLVQ1SAovCHbPKnQKCnCqiTPK8VA3SbW31C3JzHQHGFcO1/"]}
]

Problems
Some fields in the JSON output are incorrect, with data from one request appearing to persist into another item. #SOLVED WITH DOWNLOAD DELAYS
The incorrect fields are not consistent across different attempts. #SOLVED WITH DOWNLOAD DELAYS
The number of items in the JSON output file doesn't match the number of items in the .txt file. #SOLVED BY ADDING DUPEFILTER AS SUGGESTED BY @wRAR
The number of items in the JSON output file varies across different attempts. #SOLVED WITH DUPEFILTER AS SUGGESTED BY @wRAR
Expected Behavior
Each item in the JSON file should be independent and contain only the data present on its respective URL. #SOLVED WITH DOWNLOAD DELAYS
The JSON file should contain the same number of items as the .txt file. #SOLVED WITH DUPEFILTER AS SUGGESTED BY @wRAR
What I've Tried
Adding if-else conditions to set "NO DATA FOUND" as a placeholder when data isn't found. DOESN'T WORK
Ensuring ItemLoader is instantiated afresh for each response. DOESN'T WORK
Confirming that the URLs in my source file are correct. DOESN'T WORK
Double-check that no other parts of the code are sharing states, such as class-level variables or improperly scoped data structures.
Use a random user agent. DOESN'T WORK
Using randomized download delays. DOESN'T WORK
Using a download delay of 2 seconds. WORKS
What works?
Well, the download delay works. But for scraping 120 sites, it goes from 47 seconds (without the delay) to 1247 secons (21 minutes).
Is there an alternative way to ensure consistent data without significantly increasing runtime?

The provided code is correct, so the cause of your problems is in the code you didn't provide.

@wRAR, thank you for your answer. I don't have much more code: a 'DeepLinks.txt' file; the python file '2_ProjectFinder_SoF.py'; the json file produced. I've edited the post to give a little bit more information.
I've double-checked, and the JSON file has 101 entries instead of the 128 expected, which suggests a potential issue with how the DeepLinks.txt file is being read. But I don't get how

If you want help with some code you need to provide a complete minimal reproducible example and explain the problems you actually have. If you don't want to provide the whole input file, provide an input file that is enough to reproduce the problem. And "the JSON file has 101 entries instead of the 128 expected" suggests you may have several problems.

Yes you're right. I've updated the post to include the complete .txt file. I'm getting the problem running the code provided and the .txt file, I don't have more files or code.

I've also included the first 32 lines of the json file, I can't include the whole file due to character limitation

It's a problem with the website, not with item loaders. You can confirm that by deleting all item-related code and just saving and comparing the extracted data in a class attribute.

Thanks for the suggestion—I'd like to explore this further. I've been manually verifying the website content, and it appears correct when I access it directly.
Given that the website seems consistent when I check it manually, why could the data be inconsistent during scraping? Are there particular reasons why a website might serve different content to a scraper versus a regular browser, even if the content itself is not dynamic?

I don't think it won't be consistent when you access it via a spider when you also access just one page, like you do in a browser.

The URLs in the json file are correct, so how can the URL be consistent while the other items in the same line are inconsistent? Also, why is there a discrepancy in the number of entries between the JSON file and the TXT file?

The disrepancy is because of the dupefilter. Why exactly does the website return the wrong data for some pages is a separate question that you can try investigating yourself.

Dupefilter worked perfect! And download delays worked also for data consistency. Now I'm trying to find some other more efficient way to do it. THANK YOU!

"Dupefilter worked perfect!" makes no sense, but sure.

@Isidre regarding your question about why data could get inconsistent: The way a website is programmed could cause problems, when it has to serve too many requests. And you don't know what load you put on the site, scraping at high speed may cause problems to it in the back end. BTW, I've been at the receiving end of scraping and after I identified the problem, I made sure the scraper got special replies... in this case extra captchas, but we also considered to sometimes sending incorrect data to those requests...

@576i  Thanks for the clarification; I appreciate your insights. I’m fairly new to this and still navigating the best practices for scraping responsibly. There are no captchas on the site and have carefully reviewed and followed the robots.txt file, but didn’t thought about overloading the server.
